# Set a prop element to the state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm mapping an object array and passing it as a prop where I'm populating it, one by one as bellow.

```
const bottomData = [
{
    name: 'Beneficial Owner Details',
    id:'1',
},

{
    name: 'Residential Address',
    id:'2',
},]

 mapData() {
    return bottomData.map(list => <Card key={list.id} dataItems={list}/>)

 }
```

This is where I extract the object and populate the details as I desire.

```
export default class Card extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        sectionId: ''
    }
 }

sectionPress() {
 if (this.props.dataItems.id == "1"){
    alert("ID is 1")
 }
}
 render() {
    return (
   <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.sectionPress}>
     <View >
        <Text>{this.props.dataItems.name}</Text>         
     </View>
   </TouchableHighlight>
    )
 }
}
```

My objective is to display an alert with the "id" number of the object being clicked. As of now I get an error saying "Cannot read the property dataItems of undefined". What am I missing here.I tried it with setting it to the state too but didn't work and gave the same error.

Comment: Component props are readonly

Comment: I can populate all the names in the text though but cant get the id and assign it to a state property why is that